# Cropping a rectangle out of Camera2 Image

Tags: android, image, image-processing, android-camera2

I have a YUV_420_888 image I got from the camera. I want to crop a rectangle out of grayscale of this image to feed to an image processing algorithm. This is what I have so far:

```
public static byte[] YUV_420_888toCroppedY(Image image, Rect cropRect) {
    byte[] yData;

    ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();

    int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();

    yData = new byte[ySize];

    yBuffer.get(yData, 0, ySize);

    if (cropRect != null) {

        int cropArea = (cropRect.right - cropRect.left) * (cropRect.bottom - cropRect.top);

        byte[] croppedY = new byte[cropArea];

        int cropIndex = 0;

        // from the top of the rectangle, to the bottom, sequentially add rows to the output array, croppedY
        for (int y = cropRect.top; y < cropRect.top + cropRect.height(); y++) {

            // (2x+W) * y + x
            int rowStart = (2*cropRect.left + cropRect.width()) * y + cropRect.left;

            // (2x+W) * y + x + W
            int rowEnd = (2*cropRect.left + cropRect.width()) * y + cropRect.left + cropRect.width();

            for (int x = rowStart;  x < rowEnd; x++) {
                croppedY[cropIndex] = yData[x];
                cropIndex++;
            }
        }

        return croppedY;
    }

    return yData;
}
```

This function runs without error but the image I get out of it is garbage - it looks something like this:

[image]

I'm not sure how to solve this problem or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think you should post the original image

Comment: @YandryPozo I don't have it, I looked through my preview screen and it doesn't look like that

Comment: You might find the answer by reading up on gralloc and android buffers: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-bq-gralloc. This is a nice overview which also explains why the width of the buffer in bytes might differ from the width of the image in pixels: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/991640/androids-graphics-buffer-management-system-part-i

Answer (score 1):

Your rowStart/end calculations are wrong.

You need to calculate the row start location based on the source image dimensions, not on your crop window dimensions. And I'm not sure where you get the factor of 2 from; there's 1 byte per pixel in the Y channel of the image.

They should be roughly:

```
int yRowStride = image.getPlanes()[0].getRowStride();
..
int rowStart = y * yRowStride + cropRect.left();
int rowEnd = y * yRowStride + cropRect.left() + cropRect.width();
```